# Regarding $x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered several times with the ODE
$$x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}=0,$$
and I don't know some specific general theory which allows me to address it. I have sincerely no idea of how to obtain a general solution for this ODE; it is clear that both the trivial solution and $(x(t),y(t))=(Ce^t,De^t)$, with $C,D$ some non-zero constants, are solutions for the ODE, but I can't come up with anything more. Moreover, when trying to search for it on the internet nothing arises. Do you know any reference about this equation?

Comment: **Hint:** What is $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}t (y/x)$?

Answer (score 3):

Let us have a geometrical look at the issue.

The differential equation expresses the fact that the dot product :

$$(x,y).(-y',x')=0$$

Besides, we also have:

$$(x,y).(-y,x)=0$$

Therefore, $(-y',x')$ and $(-y,x)$ both orthogonal to $(x,y)$, are proportional, meaning that there is a function $f$ such that :

$$(-y',x')=f(t) \times (-y,x)$$

We are left with 2 separate differential equations:

$$\begin{cases}y'(t)=f(t)y(t)\\ x'(t)=f(t)x(t)\end{cases}$$

and assuming $x(t)\ne 0$ and $y(t) \ne 0$:

$$\begin{cases}y'(t)/y(t)=f(t)\\ x'(t)/x(t)=f(t)\end{cases}$$

Can you take it from here ?

**Comment :** behind all this is the fact that the vector derivative (the speed) is proportional to the tangent vector, giving **circular motions with variable speed**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $x,y\neq 0$ you can rewrite it as
$$ \frac{\dot{y}}{y} = \frac{\dot{x}}{x}$$
which after $\int dt$ means that
$$ \ln y(t) = \ln x(t) + C$$
$$ y(t) = \tilde C\, x(t) $$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. $x(t)$ can be an arbitrary function.

Setting $\tilde C = 0$ takes care of the case $y(t)=0$.

It can be checked that $x(t) = 0$, and $y(t)$ being an arbitrary function also satisfies this equation.